# nav tab selection causes screen to scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I understand something like this has been asked before, but none of the suggestions have resolved my issue.

I have 2 nav tabs and each one shows one chart.js graph with some data. A country is chosen from a drop down select picker and the charts will update. The default chart will show without any issues. But when I choose the second tab, the screen will scroll up to the bottom of the previous section's div and then show the chart. This will happen once every time I make a selection in the dropdown select picker and then select the tab which is not focused. After than I can click whichever tab without this issue.

So, On first load this happens and any consequtive selection from the selectpicker that causes the charts to redraw.

I tried this but it does not help

```html
<div class="card mb-4">
  <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="picker" data-size="10"></select>
</div>
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-daily-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#nav-daily-by-country" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">DailyNumbers</a>
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-cumulative-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#nav-cumulative-by-country" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Cumulative Numbers</a>
</nav>
```

```js
$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

I've tried using: `$(document).scrollTop()` to reset the window back, but it simply will not work unless the redrawn charts have been rendered at least once each. This is rather mind boggling. Nothing in the css regarding scrolling either.

Another thing I've noticed is that as long as the window location is still within the div above the one my selectpicker and nav is, it will not scroll.

Comment: `preventDefault()` isn't working for you because your selector is wrong, hence the event isn't being bound. There's no `li` in your HTML. Use `$('.nav-tabs a')` and it'll work

Comment: This still does not work. Using $('.nav-tabs a') does invoke the click event, but the behavior remains the same.

Comment: You may need to add a `href` attribute to the `a` elements in order for them to invoke a click event

Comment: I had used href before and now using data-target on both of the nav-items. The click event is invoked with both. It's just that e.preventDefault(); doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there any more information that I can provide?